# How to know what object or piece of code is continually consuming memory when App is really in idle state in iOS 7 with Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, memory-management

As the title described, I'm wandering what's going on that my app is continually consuming more and more memory when it is really in idle state?

Would it have something todo with the ADBannerView? It's the only object who is continually doing its own work when the app is in idle state. But logically it doesn't.

I have already checked the memory leak matter by Profile and Analyze, they reported nothing, and there have no zombies, and every time when I pause the app, it always stop at the mach_msg_trap, everything seems ok.

I have used the Allocation Instruments to profile the app for about 2 hours in idle state, the allocation curve didn't change in the whole 2 hours and remained at a very low level.

But int he Xcode, the memory consumption continually goes higher and higher, when the app has run abut 20 minutes, there comes the memory warnings, and then about 20 minutes later, the app is terminated because of memory shortage.

The testing device is iPhone 4S

Comment: Use the Allocations section of Instruments to see what is using up the memory.

Comment: @rmaddy : I used the allocation instrument for about 2 hours, it reported everything ok too.

Comment: Then your app isn't consuming more and more memory.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your answer. But how would you explain the memory consumption issue in Xcode?

Comment: The memory for Xcode is rising or the app? If your app is growing memory, the Allocations instrument will show it. Don't look for leaks, look for object count growing over time, then drill down and find out which objects those are.

Comment: @KirbyTodd, Thanks for help. But the Allocations Instrument shows everything is ok. Maybe that's the Xcode's bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profile with Allocations instrument and watch it at idle for a while.